# Web development for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing a website for the iPhone. Need to get some specks on optimum page sizes and control sizes and best practices for iPhone Web Developement. I know that it runs a full size browser but I want to optomise the site for the iPhone screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apple's IPhone Web Apps Guidelines](https://web.archive.org/web/20090701221013/http://developer.apple.com/webapps/designingcontent.php) tell you all this info. Click on "Optimize for Page Readability".

Comment: Thanks @Asaph - looks like it has everything I need

Comment: The page _designingcontent.php_ is now only available on archive.org.

Answer (score 1):

[iPhoneWebDev](http://www.iphonewebdev.com/) has useful resources.

Also, [iPhone Web Development Tips](http://ajaxian.com/archives/iphone-web-development-tips-and-official-documentation-released).

Answer (score 1):

I've used this page layout successfully for iPhone (landscape and portrait).

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts

I really don't like going to websites that feed me a 960 fixed layout on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [provides guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/iPhoneWebAppHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) for this.

Answer (score -1):

Try poking around here: http://developer.apple.com/safari/